# Sort Stacked Barchart in OAC

Tags: oracle, visualization, oas

I am using Oracle Analytics Cloud to visualise volume of items by day of week. I am using a stacked barchart and it is not obvious to me how to re-order/sort the visual i.e. I want the bottom segment to be Monday, next Tuesday etc. but OAC is sorting them alphabetically and will only allow me sort them similarly i.e. reverse alphabetically.

Is there a way to sort the stacked barchart by day of week i.e. Mon-Sun?

Answer (score 0):

The "Weekday" attribute of the full date format fixed my issue. I had been using a completely separate "Day" attribute which was treated as Text and therefore sorted alphabetically.